# I need a Python function that can fit a curve within a parameter space

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting

I've been working on a project that uses SciPy's **optimize.curve_fit()** function to fit a curve to some data by varying 3 parameters, which has been working well.

However, I now need to alter the program so that 1 of the parameters has bounds which are a function of another parameter (e.g. when x = 10 ybounds = 1 +/- 0.2 but when x = 11 ybounds = 1.1 +/- 0.2). The only idea I've had so far is to put another **optimize.curve_fit()** function inside the first one, but this has proved hugely inefficient (program now takes ~4 hours rather than 5 mins).

Are there any other Python functions I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: You can try a "brick wall" technique, where your function returns a very large value (and therefore a very large error) if the parameter is outside the bounds. This is a somewhat crude technique as parameter values at or very near the bounds have obviously not been well defined, however it can be useful and is certainly easy to test. Note that for calculation of parameter statistics after fitting has been completed, the restriction on parameter value must be removed or the post-fitting parameter statistics may be calculated incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find lmfit (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py) for what you are trying to do.   Among other features, `lmfit` allows constraining parameters using mathematical expressions depending on other parameters without changing the details of the function used to model the data.

As a simple example, you could have a parameter named `a` vary freely, and another parameter `b` defined to be `1-sqrt(a)`.

Comment: I see that this particular answer lacks disclosure about you being an author of that package. Normally I'd flag this but you seem to have added disclosures to your recent answers. Please [edit] and add a disclosure.