# How can I find the best fit of a curve where one of the parameters has a Lognormal distribution in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting, normal-distribution

In a project I've been working on I have been using SciPy's **optimize.curve_fit()** function to fit curve to a graph by varying 3 parameters. One of the parameters (c) needs to be constrained within limits based on another parameter (Mhalo) as you can see in the graph [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewBkX.png).

As the next step in the project I want to change this relation so that instead of varying c within limits based on Mhalo, as shown in the graph, the c parameter has a lognormal distribution around the Mhalo-c relation.

When I've tried to do this by taking c out of the variables in the **optimize.curve_fit()** function and putting a random lognormal calculation inside the function I am fitting instead, the program fails to fit a curve at all (presumably because of the random element).

Is there any way I can accomplish what I've described here either using **optimize.curve_fit()** or a different function in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to [I need a Python function that can fit a curve within a parameter space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359762/i-need-a-python-function-that-can-fit-a-curve-within-a-parameter-space/49363237#49363237).  It is not quite a duplicate.

Are `c` and `Mhalo` meant to be fitting parameters?

As also mentioned in the earlier question, you might find `lmfit` helpful.  It can allow one parameter to be defined as a simple (or maybe not so simple) mathematical expression of other parameters.  For example, it might be that what your looking to do is constrain `c` to be some function of `Mhalo` plus some term that has finite bounds.  That might be done in `lmfit` with something like

```
 from lmfit import Parameters

 params = Parameters()
 params.add('mhalo', value=100, vary=True)
 params.add('c_offset', value=0, min=-1, max=1, vary=True) 

 params.add('c', expr='log10(mhalo) + c_offset')
```

That will allow `mhalo` to vary freely, allow `c_offset` to vary within bounds, and constrain `c` to be a function of these two parameters, meaning that `c` can change in the fit but not independently of `mhalo` and `c_offset`.